# Method with Generic Type, set value

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I have a method which is something like below and i want to set the value of it with input string.

How would i go about it? Any advice will be greatly appreciated

```
private static void QueueCheckNAdd<T>(ref T param, string input)
    {
        param.DoSomethingLikeSetValue(input);
    }
```

for your reference, the generic type is something like int or double

Comment: If `T` will only be either `int` or `double`, you may want to just write a couple concrete methods to perform the conversion using `int.Parse()` and `double.Parse()`. Your method is not really generic if it can only be used with a small, fixed set of types. Using concrete methods also allows you to write the methods without casts.

Comment: Side note: there is no really good way to restrict generic type to `int`/`double` - so if you are writing code that may be used you need to verify that it can work with all allowed types....

Comment: I wanted to consider that one day i might have to accommodate for different types. I meant that right now its only assigned to data types of int and double

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
param = (T)(object)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(T));
```

The casts are necessary to convince the compiler that the result is really of type `T`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for days!    How did you figure this bit arcane magic out?

Answer (score 2):

You want `param` to be generic (i.e., any type), *and* you expect to be able to call some method on it, correct?  Well, you can see the problem there: if `param` can be any type, there's no way to guarantee that it will have the method `DoSomethingLikeSetValue` (or whatever).  I'm sure you could get fancy with introspection or runtime type coercion, but I think the "clean" way to do what you're looking for is to constrain the type of `T` to some interface that has the required method (`DoSomethingLikeSetValue`).  Like this:

```
private static void QueueCheckNAdd<T>(ref T param, string input) where T : IHasSomething {
    param.DoSomethingLikeSetValue(input);
}

public interface IHasSomething {
    void DoSomethingLikeSetValue(string s);
}
```

Then you can invoke `QueueCheckNAdd` generically only if the generic type supports the `IHasSomething` interface.  So you could use it like this:

```
public class Foo : IHasSomething {
    public void DoSomethingLikeSetValue(string s) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

var f = new Foo();
QueueCheckNAdd<Foo>(f, "hello");
```

Comment: While good suggestion you can't really do that for built in types as you can't add interfaces to existing types...

Comment: That's true, Alexei...and that begs the question "if you can't do it, should you be doing it?"  At the end of the day, if type safety is such a huge inconvenience, you should probably think about using a type-free language.  Yes, this problem can be solved by RTTI or other methods, but it indicates to me that there's a bigger architectural issue.

Comment: This is also a very nice method, i will keep this in mind. But i will go with SLaks's answer because it is even cleaner. Although it may be slower in performance

Answer (score 1):

Good practice would be to use interface like described before,

But if you want some fun, you could aslo use the object as a dynamic object, like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class SMTHG
    {
        public void DoSomethingLikeSetValue(string input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HEYYYYY!!! DYNAMIC OBJECTS FTW!...\n" + input);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static void QueueCheckNAdd<T>(ref T param, string input)
        {
            dynamic dynamicObject = (dynamic)param; 
            dynamicObject.DoSomethingLikeSetValue(input);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SMTHG smthg = new SMTHG();
            QueueCheckNAdd(ref smthg, "yoyuyoyo");
        }
    }
}
```